# VB.NET Using VbStrConv.ProperCase with multi-case names?

Tags: vb.net, string, string-formatting

In VB.NET, is there a way to use `VbStrConv.ProperCase` on strings with multiple cases?

For example, if the string to convert is `"McGreggor"`, using `.ProperCase` on this will change it to `"Mcgreggor"`, which is incorrect for someone's name. The same is applied with `"O'Neil"` turning into `"O'neil"` and other similarly formatted names.

**EDIT**: I also need it to still comply to `.ProperCase`'s rules. EG: `JOHN` becomes `John`, and `McGReGgor` would become `McGreggor`.

Is there any way to do this, or am I out of options?

Answer (score 2):

How about a regex to uppercase a single a-z following whitespace?

```
Dim text As String = "McGreggor O'Neil smith jones"

text = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(text, "\s([a-z])",
            Function(m)
                Return m.Value.ToUpper()
            End Function)
```

> "McGreggor O'Neil Smith Jones"

Comment: Seems good, however that won't lowercase non-first letters will it? Essentially I need something that does exactly what .ProperCase does, but with the added exceptions above (and its variants).

Comment: I would split on " ", then loop each word, lowecase it, compare to a known list of exceptions like `mc`, `o'` and apply uppercasing as appropriate